# MYSQL query to compare and update tables

Tags: mysql, updates

Please help create a query using mysql.
I have two tables:
table_E and table-I.

[image]

Description my query :

```
Select table_E.obj_id and find obj_id in table_I.
learn table_I.field_id, where the same varchar_val tables .
If table_I.field = 483 , upgrade table_I.float_val ( where table_I.field = 268) , the value table_E.float_val
If table_I.field = 484 , upgrade table_I.float_val ( where table_I.field = 467 ) , the value table_E.float_val
...
If table_I.field = 499 , upgrade table_I.float_val ( where table_I.field = 482) , the value table_E.float_val
```

and a second database , such as :

```
Select table_E.obj_id and find obj_id in table_I.
learn table_I.field_id, where the same varchar_val tables .
If table_I.field = 483 , upgrade table_I.varchar_val ( where table_I.field = 446 ) , the value table_E.old_p
If table_I.field = 484 , upgrade table_I.varchar_val ( where table_I.field = 515 ) , the value table_E.old_p
...
If table_I.field = 499 , upgrade table_I.varchar_val ( where table_I.field = 271 ) , the value table_E.old_p
```

Comment: What do you want here. Please provide some more information.. What is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL Utilities](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/utilities/) have a tool called mysqldiff: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.4/en/mysqldiff.html

> This utility reads the definitions of objects and compares them using a diff-like method to determine whether they are the same. The utility displays the differences for objects that are not the same.
>
> ...
>
> By default, the utility generates object differences as a difference report. However, you can generate a transformation report containing SQL statements for transforming the objects for conformity instead.

You can get the utilities from the download link above, or as part of MySQL Workbench.